# Вывод значений чекбоксов при их выборе

Tags: javascript, php

есть функция на php которая считает количество записей получаемых из базы, после чего создает столько же инпутов с одним и тем же id. и есть функция на js которая должна считать сумму значений этих чекбоксов. как написать js под эту задачу, потому что тот js который есть выводит только значение первого чекбокса.

```
document.getElementById('checkbox').addEventListener('change', toggleInput); 

function toggleInput(evt) { 
  document.querySelector('.input-email').classList.toggle('hidden-div'); 
}
```

Comment: логика в том что если чекбокс выбран то должно выводится его значение или сумма значений чекбоксов если выбрано несколько

Comment: Напишите вашу js функцию и уточните вопрос. Непонятно как у вас всё работает. Как можно дать ответ, не зная с чем работаешь, и что именно вам требуется

Comment: document.getElementById('checkbox').addEventListener('change', toggleInput);
  function toggleInput(evt) {
  document.querySelector('.input-email').classList.toggle('hidden-div');
}

но выводит данный js отдельный див а не переменную

Comment: есть форма с чекбоксами и кнопкой

Comment: вообще сайт на modx. считается сумма значений чекбоксов выбранных только по кнопке ну или энтеру а нужно чтоб считалось в реальном времени

Comment: я в js не шарю поэтому пытаюсь примеры переделать под условие

Comment: есть массив на php который перебирается и подставляет каждое значение массива в value чекбокса

Comment: Ваша функция не выводит значение чекбокса

Comment: да, я знаю. в этом и проблема

Comment: я пока пытаюсь сделать что выводилось хотя бы что-то при выборе чекбоксов. а выводиться только если выбран 1-ый по списку чекбокс а не какой-либо другой

Comment: Ваша функция не выводит значение даже первого чекбокса, она бессмыслена, она ничего не делает, переформулируйте вопрос

Comment: могу адрес сайта скинуть для наглядности

Comment: Скидывайте, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: https://shablon.test28.ru/kalkulyator

Comment: вот если выбрать чекбокс 1 то выводится инпут а если выбрать какой-либо другой то нет

Comment: Если не трудно скажите в каком именно файле описана функция которая выводит значение чекбокса

Comment: в сниппете передаются значения из формы там суммируются и выводятся через банальное эхо

Comment: могу код скинуть его

Comment: хотя бы почему только для первого чекбокса действует js

Comment: Так у Вас идет поиск по _идентификатору_, который, по логике, должен быть в единственном экземпляре, ведь это **идентификатор**. Функция и ищет первый id, игнорируя остальные. Уберите id-шки, воспользуйтесь классами, и будет Вам счастье